# SQL Count syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble counting two things in an SQL query. I need to pull a list of files that have been accessed at least five times each by employees from both marketing and sales. I know I'm using `COUNT` incorrectly but I don't know how. Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT FileId
FROM Files
JOIN FileAccesses ON Files.FileId = FileAccesses.FileId
WHERE Count(AccessUserGroup=1)>5 AND Count(AccessUserGroup=2)>5
```

It produces the error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

`Files` is a table with the `int` `FileId` as its primary key. `FileAccesses` stores `FileId` values from `Files` but not as the primary key. It keeps track of a bunch of metadata every time a user touches a file. For the purposes of this question, the part that matters is `AccessUserGroup`, a `tinyint` that is set to `1` for marketing and `2` for sales.

Comment: Use `group by` and `having`.

Comment: Use HAVING COUNT(...) Instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query that you want:

```
SELECT fa.FileId
FROM FileAccesses fa 
GROUP BY fa.FileId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN AccessUserGroup = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 5 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN AccessUserGroup = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 5;
```

Notes:

- You don't need the`JOIN`, unless your `FileAccesses` could have a file id not in `Files` (which I consider unlikely).
- You should be using `GROUP BY` if you want to use aggregation functions.
- The comparisons go in the `HAVING` clause.
- The `COUNT()` with an expression produces an error in SQL Server (it works in some other databases).  `SUM()` with `CASE` does the conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need the actual file info as well not just the file id, so you can use a cte (common table expression) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

```
    ;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT FileAccesses.FileId FROM FileAccesses 
    GROUP BY FileId
    HAVING COUNT(CASE AccessUserGroup WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 5 
    AND COUNT(CASE AccessUserGroup WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 5
    )
    SELECT * FROM File 
    INNER JOIN cte ON File.FileId = cte.FileId
```